# Error while deploy: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem not found

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, sbt

I am trying to write a parquet file in Scala/sbt. My code works fine on my computer but always fails when deploy on a server with Jenkins.
I have the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2688)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3431)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:288)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:524)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.fromPath(HadoopOutputFile.java:58)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter$Builder.build(ParquetWriter.java:677)
at com.github.mjakubowski84.parquet4s.ParquetWriter$.internalWriter(ParquetWriter.scala:129)
at com.github.mjakubowski84.parquet4s.ParquetWriterImpl.<init>(ParquetWriter.scala:186)
at com.github.mjakubowski84.parquet4s.ParquetWriter$BuilderImpl.build(ParquetWriter.scala:111)
at com.github.mjakubowski84.parquet4s.ParquetWriter$BuilderImpl.writeAndClose(ParquetWriter.scala:113)
at ParquetExport$.$anonfun$tryExport$1(ParquetExport.scala:307)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:658)
at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2592)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2686)
... 29 more
```

I first tried to use spark:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.3.0"
```

And then changed to code to work with these:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"com.github.mjakubowski84" %% "parquet4s-core" % "2.6.0",
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.10.2"
)
```

And still encountering the same error.

Setting the Hadoop configuration didn't help:

```
val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
hadoopConfig.set("fs.hdfs.impl", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem].getname)
hadoopConfig.set("fs.hdfs.impl", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem].getname)
```

Neither did changing the ClassLoader:
`Thread.currentThread.setContextClassLoader(getClass.getClassLoader)`

Everything work fine in local but not on the server. Any idea?

Comment: `spark-core` already includes `hadoop-client` as a dependency, you shouldn't need to add it manually. Also, you want `fs.file.impl` set to `org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem`, which should be the default, anyway... Are you properly building an assembly JAR with SBT?

Answer (score 1):

I already faced the same issue.

If you look at your logs :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2592)
```

You understand that it can't find the name of the class **LocalFileSystem** you set to your hadoop config.

Try to change this :

```
val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
hadoopConfig.set("fs.hdfs.impl", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem].getname)
hadoopConfig.set("fs.hdfs.impl", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem].getname)
```

To :

```
 val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
 hadoopConfig.set("fs.hdfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem")
 hadoopConfig.set("fs.file.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem")
```